# SVN commit txn-current-lock on Mountain Lion

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, git-svn

I have facing SVN problem in Mac OS X ..

When i am commit any file below are the error are generate.

**svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't get exclusive lock on file '/Volumes/SvnProject/db/txn-current-lock': Operation not supported**

Comment: do you use a "file:///" protocol to a access a repository? Check this thread http://superuser.com/questions/401570/mac-svn-client-cant-commit-to-tortoise-svn-server

Comment: Yes i am using file:// protocol ...

Answer (score 1):

On the SVN server, ensure that the owner and group of the repository (and all subfolders) are properly set.

For example, I created a repo by issuing the following from the SVN server as root:

```
svnadmin create /path/myrepo
```

Initially I was getting the **txn-current-lock** error from my SVN client.  On the SVN server, I noticed that `/path/myrepo` and all of its subfolders had `owner:group` of `root:root`.  To fix this, I issued the following from the SVN server:

```
chown -R newowner:newgroup
```

Ensure your newowner and newgroup items match the owner/group information being supplied by the SVN clients.

Important to make it recursive with the -R option.  This fixed the **txn-current-lock** error.